# Azure App Service - Am I required to expose port in docker-compose

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have a node.js app that runs as a worker, so `server.listen()` not be used. The worker simply connects to a DB and performs some actions.

I have a docker-compose to run this however am noticing that if I dont include the `ports` attribute in the `docker-compose` the container fails to run i.e.:

```
ports:
   - 443:3000
```

(3000 in the above is just an example - i'm not exposing any port).

Could someone tell me why not having this causes the container to crash /what I'm mis-understanding.

(When I run the `docker-compose up worker` locally it runs as expected)

Thanks.

Comment: There's a (poorly documented) [prerequisite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux) that containers need to expose a port in order to host in an App Service. A container with no listener may run for a few seconds before being torn down. This may be a sign that you are using the wrong hosting tech - [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/functions/) may be a better bet for running 'daemons' and if you have a large docker investment, look at [AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/kubernetes-service)

Comment: Thanks - this is the answer.
So I guess I'll just have expose a port and just return a blank page to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server listens to a particular port. This line means you're routing web traffic from port 443 to 3000 (port your web server running inside your web app is listening to). Without this line you can't proper route web traffic to the port the web server is listening to, which causes it to fail the requests